# qemu/kvm: connect two machines via ttyS0

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, tty

I would like to connect two machines via ttyS0

Here's what I did on the guest machines:

A:

- Add to /etc/inittab:

  `S0:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty ttyS0`
- Add to /etc/securetty:

  `ttyS0`

B:

- Try to connect to A

  `cu -l /dev/ttyS0`

Here's what I did on the host machine:

```
mkfifo /tmp/serialbridge
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda A.qcow2 -net nic -net user -m 2048 -enable-kvm -cpu host -machine type=pc,accel=kvm -serial pipe:/tmp/serialbridge
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda B.qcow2 -net nic -net user -m 2048 -enable-kvm -cpu host -machine type=pc,accel=kvm -serial pipe:/tmp/serialbridge
```

I guess the paramter "-serial pipe:/tmp/serialbridge" is wrong. Any ideas how to fix that?

(Qemu is self-compiled from the latest Git tree.)

Result: cu doesn't show login, but rather seems stuck. The other machine seems to hang after login screen. Both run Debian Squeeze.

Comment: did you add `console=ttyS0` to the kernel opts in grub in the guests?

Comment: No, adding console=ttyS0 didn't help.